# Post Sort Order

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to re-order my posts which reflect - currently they are in alphabetical order. I need them in "menu-order" - as I have sorted them on the page attributes.

I have tried a custom post order plugin but this does not affect the sort order.

I have also tried the below:

Original:

```
$_department_services       = get_post_meta( $id, "{$cpt}_department_services", true );
```

Attempt to add  menu-order:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'posts_order_wpse_91866' );

function posts_order_wpse_91866() 
{
    add_post_type_support( 'department_services', 'page-attributes' );
}
```

```
$_department_services       = get_post_meta( $id, "{$cpt}_department_services", true );
$_doctors                   = get_post_meta( $id, "{$cpt}_doctor", true );
$_emergency_cases           = get_post_meta( $id, "{$cpt}_emergency_cases", true );   
$_opening_hour              = get_post_meta( $id, "{$cpt}_opening_hour", true );
$doctors                    = Helper::get_departments_doctor($_doctors);   
$order_posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'department_services', 
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
) );
?>
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91875/137579) answer?

Comment: @rits - would that first part go in functions.php - and the query in my same file where i have the above?

Comment: Yes, use the query where you need to get posts.

Comment: That attempt is not even valid PHP syntax, that would only give you an error / “blank page”. Plus, `get_post_meta` gets meta data for a single post, so this is likely not even the correct place to look – unless you have some sort of setup where this meta data field itself contained a list of posts, and that list is what you actually want to order. (But then you should give us a better description of how your setup actually works.)

Comment: @rits i have updated my question to reflect the latest changes. please kindly see where I went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please user "Post Types Order" Plugin, and redorder them with the drag and drop option.
After that remove **orderby** and **order** from the query like this.

```
$order_posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'department_services', 
    'post_status' => 'publish' 
) );
```

https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/